# How should I fill in pits in a concrete floor so I can install laminate?

Tags: concrete, floor, subfloor

I have these holes in the concrete floor, and I want to install laminate floor. What can I do to fill in these holes to get a nice level surface.

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for "floor leveling compound" yet? I believe there is such a product that you can mix, pour and then lay laminate (or just about anything)

Comment: Well i am in Ecuador so things are quite different here. The idea is to get the kind of product needed, cement, concrete etc and then ask for something resembling it. Also if you know of any sika branded products we have a great deal of those here.

Comment: Good point. I think anything like a portland cement mixed without aggregate might do. That would most closely mimic the concrete in place, and be smooth enough to work by hand. I fixed some poorly formed concrete steps with a similar mix.

Comment: The kind of product needed: Ardex NA is what I used. But I had much bigger problems than those small holes: I had lifted some old tiles which meant there were high bits (where I hadn't got enough tile adhesive off) and low bits (where the adhesive came away with some of the concrete screed). I recommend DA01's answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to fill pits of that size. The laminate floor will easily span that no problem.

Comment: +1 I am absolutely in agreement with DA01. Using the OP's foot as a scale, those pits are too small to worry about. Using a levelling compound will probably give you greater lumps (based on my own experience of using a levelling compound).

Comment: thanks. Do y'all know how much laminate flooring weights. I need to see if i can possibly buy 1OO feet of it to take to Ecuador. Its much cheaper in the US and im here for now

Comment: @DA01 At what size would you recommend filling divots in concrete? I have normal divots around the edges from removing carpet tack strips, but I also have on random one in the middle of my floor that's fairly shallow, but about 1.75" across.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I wouldn't worry about the edge divots at all...as no one walks along the edge. 1.75" is still pretty small IMHO. I'd say a divot would have to be as big as the width of one plank before I'd worry too much about it in a high traffic area.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the depth of the pits, you might be able to use sanded grout to get a nice smooth surface. Just be sure to let it dry and cure before laying down the flooring. You may need to apply it in multiple coats to get a perfect surface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use epoxy concrete patch. Note your floor needs to be flat, meaning no bumps or ridges. It can be sloped in one direction consistently, but it has to be flat.